# Add custom attributes when serializing Object to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

is it possible to have a declarative markup for a C# object model in order to generate something like this:

```
 ...
 <locales>
    <add id="698" code="tr" name="Turkish" xsd:Transform="Insert"/>
    <add id="701" code="fr" name="French" />
 </locales>
 ....
```

instead of :

```
  ...
  <locales>
    <add d5p1:Transform="Insert" Locator="asdasdf" id="698" code="tr" name="Turkish" xmlns:d5p1="xdt" />
    <add id="701" code="fr" name="French" />
  </locales>
  ...
```

a simple example of my code is:

```
public class BaseTransformation
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string IsDefault { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(Namespace ="xdt")]
    public string Transform { get; set; }

    //[XmlAttribute("Locator")]
    public string Locator { get; set; }       
}


public class Locale : BaseTransformation
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Languages
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "locales")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "add")]
    public Locale[] Locales { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to generate dynamically web.config transformations. 
**d5p1:Transform="Insert" xmlns:d5p1="xdt"** those two are not recognizable
on build and does not apply the same functionality as intended.

Comment: Just specify the namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.namespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaveM That's what I did on property "Trasnform" ...

Comment: Private properties will not be included in xml.  So make properties private.

Comment: The problem is it is serializing this -> d5p1:Transform="Insert" xmlns:d5p1="xdt"................. and I need only xdt:Transform="Insert"

Comment: @jdweng I am not having issues with which properties are being included

Comment: XML namespaces and XML namespace shortcuts are not the same. You are trying to specify a namespace shortcut instead of the actual namespace.

Comment: @DaveM does that mean .. my task is impossible to do?

Comment: no, it means you need to learn about how xml namespaces work, the xsd part is not the namespace, its a shortcut to the full, actual namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx

Comment: since you are using the namespace shortcut 'xsd' I figure you are probably wanting the namespace: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (that's not intended to be hyperlink, that's the actual namespace)

Comment: @DaveM and that's how my XML starts: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
...
isn't this actually setting the xdt shortcut ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing XML namespace prefixes with actual namespaces. In the `Namespace` property of `XmlAttribute`, you specify the full actual namespace, not the prefix you defined for that namespace. Namespace prefixes are arbitrary, and you can use whatever prefix you wish with a particular namespace using the `xmlns` attribute. The serialize thinks you are talking about a namespace called "xdt", not the actual namespace the "xdt" namespace typically refers to: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"

```
[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform")]
public string Transform { get; set; }
```

Comment: And I was indeed misinterpreting the two .. thus my confusion